# Mysql Perl module issues on Mac

Tags: mysql, perl, syntax, driver, perl-module

Have installed the Mysql Perl module and double checked(see #3 below), but still get error(#1 below) when using.

If I use the `DBD::Mysql`, then the connect statement [`Mysql->connect('localhost')`] doesn't work (#2 below)

Have tried all syntax combos per documentation including capitalization of spelling, etc.

On Mac OS X 10.6.

TIA,
Gary

### 1.

```
Can't locate Mysql.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0 /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Network/Library/Perl /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0 .)
```

### 2:

```
Can't locate object method "connect" via package "mysql" (perhaps you forgot to load "mysql"?)
```

### 3:

```
cpan[1]> install DBD::mysql
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.18)
Going to read '/private/var/root/Library/Application Support/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sat, 04 Dec 2010 00:31:51 GMT
DBD::mysql is up to date (4.018).
```

Answer (score 3):

[`DBD::mysql`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3amysql) is the database driver. You should not be using it directly in normal cases. Instead, you should use [`DBI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI) with a MySQL specific connection string.

**Example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my %db = (
    'database' => 'leaking_wiki',
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'port'     => '3306',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 't0p_53cr3t',
);

my $dbh = DBI->connect(                                                                                                                                      
    "DBI:mysql:database=$db{database};host=$db{host};port=$db{port}",                                                                                        
    $db{username}, $db{password} )                                                                                                                           
  or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Comment: seems to get past that error, although stuck with several other in trying to port some old Perl code - didn't find this anywhere by searching or documentation - so a genuine tip of the hat to you!

Comment: Hi, after going thru' some other errors, now am getting this - thanks for any help - dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace